# Libreoffice Base Custom function

Tags: libreoffice-base

I created a custom LibreOffice Basic function:

```
Function Test()
Test = True
End Function
```

Then I created a query

```
SELECT Field1, Test() "Test" FROM Table
```

I get

```
SQL Status: HY000

Can not execute query. The function is not compatible.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Edit:

I am trying to get calculated fields in a query. I know how to do that with Microsoft Access so I thought there was a similar way to do it with LibreOffice Base. The LibreOffice database is a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet.

I have googled "LibreOffice base custom functions" and "OpenOffice base custom functions" and got only results for LibreOffice Calc and OpenOffice Calc. Also searched here in Stack Overflow without finding an acceptable answer.

Comment: What engine are you using?  I tried this using embedded HSQLDB 1.8 and received the error message "Access is denied: TEST in statement".  Anyway, that's not how Base works.  It seems you have a mistaken idea about [stored procedures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure).  Please explain what you are trying to accomplish, and tell what documentation you have researched online.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: In Access this functionality exists.  In Base, sorry to say, this functionality does does not (yet) exist to use functions within SQL.  For one, suggest you go to LO bugs and chime in as a new desired feature.  After that you're going to have to get creative.  Sometimes you can build sql in Basic to get around this.